# Command pattern push all commands to stack

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns, controls

I have two custom `Control` classes, `Box`and `Ellipse`. I'm able to draw, drag and resize them. Now I'm trying to implement unlimited undo and redo. I use the `Command Pattern` for this. My `Box` class look exactly the same as the `Ellipse` class with the difference that the `Box` class paints a box shape. At the moment when I paint an `Ellipse` and for example move /resize this control I'm able to go one step back, because adding makes the stacksize 1 and one undo makes the stacksize 0 again. Only when I add the `Ellipse` I push the command to the `Stack` now. The resizing/moving happens in another class then the adding, but these actions also have to be pushed to the `commandStack` in `Form1`. How can I do this?

My idea was to create a stack in `Ellipse` and `Box`and call `Do` for every action and push every command to the stack (in `Ellipse` or `Box`), but this isn't gonna work I believe because the `Form` class needs to have access to the stack with all commands from all `Controls`. Anyone who can help to make unlimited undo/redo work?
I followed the example in this link: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/40e97e/command-pattern-undo-example/ .

ICommand interface

```
public interface ICommand
{
    void Do();
    void Undo();
}
```

Ellipse class

```
class Ellipse : Control, ICommand
{
    private Point mDown { get; set; }

    public Ellipse()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        this.ResizeRedraw = true;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        // Draw a black ellipse in the rectangle represented by the control.
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, Width, Height);

    }  

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        mDown = e.Location;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Call MyBase.OnMouseMove to activate the delegate. 
        base.OnMouseMove(e);


        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Location = new Point(e.X + Left - mDown.X, e.Y + Top - mDown.Y);
        }

    }

    /* Allow resizing at the bottom right corner */
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const int wmNcHitTest = 0x84;
        const int htBottomLeft = 16;
        const int htBottomRight = 17;
        if (m.Msg == wmNcHitTest)
        {
            int x = (int)(m.LParam.ToInt64() & 0xFFFF);
            int y = (int)((m.LParam.ToInt64() & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);
            Point pt = PointToClient(new Point(x, y));
            Size clientSize = ClientSize;
            if (pt.X >= clientSize.Width - 16 && pt.Y >= clientSize.Height - 16 && clientSize.Height >= 16)
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)(IsMirrored ? htBottomLeft : htBottomRight);
                return;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    int x;
    int y;
    int height;
    int width;


    private void SaveCurrentControl()
    {
        x = this.Left;
        y = this.Top;
        height = this.Height;
        width = this.Width;
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        SaveCurrentControl();
    }

    public void Undo()
    {
        this.Left = x;
        this.Top = y;
        this.Height = height;
        this.Width = width;
    }
}
```

Form class

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool draw;
    private int x, y, xe, ye;
    private Stack<ICommand> commandStack = new Stack<ICommand>();
    ICommand command  = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        menuComboBoxShape.ComboBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Item));
    }

    public enum Item
    {
        Pencil,
        Rectangle, 
        Ellipse,
    }


    private void panel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        draw = true;
        x = e.X;
        y = e.Y;
    }

    private void panel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        draw = false;
        xe = e.X;
        ye = e.Y;

        Item item; 
        Enum.TryParse<Item>(menuComboBoxShape.ComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString(), out item);

        switch (item)
        {

            case Item.Pencil:
                using (Graphics g = panel.CreateGraphics())
                    using (var pen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black))     //Create the pen used to draw the line (using statement makes sure the pen is disposed)
                    {
                        g.DrawLine(pen,new Point(x, y), new Point(xe, ye));
                    }
                break;
            case Item.Rectangle:
                var box=new Box();
                panel.Controls.Add(box);
                box.Location = new Point(x, y);
                box.Width = (xe - x);
                box.Height = (ye - y);
                break;
            case Item.Ellipse:
                var el = new Ellipse();
                panel.Controls.Add(el);
                el.Location = new Point(x, y);
                el.Width = (xe - x);
                el.Height = (ye - y);
                el.Do();
                commandStack.Push(el);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void undoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (commandStack.Count > 0)
        {
            ICommand lastCommand = commandStack.Pop();
            lastCommand.Undo();
        }
        panel.Invalidate();
    }

    private void clearAllButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel.Controls.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: From the GoF book on Command: "*support undo. The Command's Execute operation can store state for reversing its effects in the command itself. The Command interface must have an added Unexecute operation that reverses the effects of a previous call to Execute. Executed commands are stored in a history list. Unlimited-level undo and redo is achieved by traversing this list backwards and forwards calling Unexecute and Execute, respectively.*"

Comment: How can I implement it in my case? Adding happens in another class then resize/move

Comment: You should follow the pattern with its elements (Invoker, Receiver, etc.) to get the full benefit of a clean and unlimited undo. See the original pattern for more info. http://www.silversoft.net/docs/dp/hires/pat5bfso.htm